# WordPress and Ubuntu, www-data and ubuntu for FTP

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon EC2. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm also using Apache 2. I have WordPress installed on my server.

I do:

```
chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html
```

so I can edit my files as `ubuntu` via FTP. But the problem is now WordPress cannot edit files, update, or upload any files via WordPress. But if I do:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html
```

then it works.

Any way I can make it work for both `ubuntu` and `www-data` at the same time, without always switching it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have done this before, exact same scenario.

You'll need a group with ubuntu and any other users in it, call it wordpress for instance.

```
# do this as root
groupadd vpsusers
gpasswd -a ubuntu wordpress
gpasswd -a www-data wordpress
etc....
```

then you want to use a base user (ubuntu) and the group as the owner of the folder.

```
# again as root
chown -R ubuntu:wordpress /var/www/html
```

final step make the group writable

```
# again as root
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

Comment: So much searching before finding this, thank you!  You may need to add define( 'FS_METHOD' , 'direct' ) to wp-config.php to allow the plugins to update from the WP admin backend.